# How to consume a rest service hosted on remote server in asp.net mvc3 using jquery ajax ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, rest

I have a rest service. I hosted this service to IIS in my local system and consumed in an mvc3 application. It run without any error. But in the same application, I am not able to consume the rest service hosted on remote server. I have written following jquery to access it :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function () {

              $.ajax({
                  url: "http://portno/Student.svc/AutoComplete?Branch=Civil&RecordLimit=4&s_name=Linda",
                  type: "GET",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: {},
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success: function (data) {                  
                     alert(data.documentElement.childNodes[3].textContent);
                  },
                  error: function (error) {                   
                     alert("Error: " + error.text);
                   }
              });
          });
     });
```

is there any mistake here? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify the error that you're getting.  Also, it's a bit confusing.  By default Ajax does not work cross domain (meaning that the service url must be the same as domain/sub-domain as the page generating the request, your mvc3 app), but you could achieve this via jasonp.

Comment: I am getting "undefined" as error. I also tried "jsonp" , but did get the same error. Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: what line of code is returning "undefined". Could you post both jasonp attempt and your rest service sample code so i can attempt to recreate this?